# Socket.io - unable to access 'this' object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm writing a game in NodeJS with Socket.io. I have a `Player` class with a method `move()`, which gets called when the `player.move` event is triggered. This then tries to access the current object properties.

This should work fine, however when `move()` is called it creates an error since the variable `this.location` cannot be accessed. Is there a way to access this variable in any way? Thank you.

This is my code:

**main.js**

```
var io = require('socket.io')(8080);
var Player = require('./Player');

// All players
var players = {};

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    // Add a new player
    players[socket.id] = new Player(socket);

    // Remove user from the game
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        players[socket.id].__unbind();
    });
});
```

**Player.js**

```
/**
 * Player class
 * @param socket
 * @constructor
 */
function Player(socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.location = {x : 0, y : 0};
    this.__bind();
}

/**
 * Move a player
 * @param {int} x
 * @param {int} y
 */
Player.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
    this.location.x = x;
    this.location.y = y;
};

/**
 * Add event listeners
 * @private
 */
Player.prototype.__bind = function() {
    this.socket.on('player.move', this.move);
};

/**
 * Remove event listeners
 * @private
 */
Player.prototype.__unbind = function() {
    this.socket.removeListener('player.move', this.move);
};

// Exports
module.exports = Player;
```

**Generated error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of undefined
    at Socket.Player.move ...(stack trace here)
```

Comment: `this.socket.on('player.move', this.move.bind(this));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind the function calls to the Player object in order to not loose the context when it's called:

```
this.socket.on('player.move', this.move.bind(this)); //Add binding here.
```

You will have to bind all method calls you want to perform outside the Player context.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :)